# error in get data from Node.js in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner at Javascript and node JS I create very simple NodeJs express server to get some message from the client and give back the result

(actually, I found it on GitHub
https://gist.github.com/diorahman/1520485 )

but it doesn't work correctly
thanks for your help to solve this problem.

```
/*Server side Code server.js*/
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

/*app.use(express.bodyParser());*/

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})

/*app.get('/endpoint', function(req, res){
var obj = {};
obj.title = 'title';
obj.data = 'data';

console.log('params: ' + JSON.stringify(req.params));
console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
console.log('query: ' + JSON.stringify(req.query));

res.header('Content-type','application/json');
res.header('Charset','utf8');
res.send(req.query.callback + '('+ JSON.stringify(obj) + ');');
});*/

app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res){
console.log('Get request By Client');
var obj = {};
console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
res.send(req.body);
});
```

in client-side, I use this code to get data from the server

```
    /*client side code: client.html*/
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>jsonp test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"> 
   </script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){               
            $('#select_link').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('select_link clicked');

                 /*$.ajax({
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: "data=yeah",                      
                    jsonp: 'callback',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint?callback=?',                       
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });*/
                var data = {};
                data.title = "title";
                data.message = "message";

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'http://192.168.1.175:3000/endpoint',                      
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
                /*$.ajax('http://localhost:3000/endpoint', {
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function() { console.log('success');},
                        error  : function() { console.log('error');}
                });*/
            });             
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="select_div"><a href="#" id="select_link">Test</a></div>    
</body>
```

really I need this code because of I am writing a project with Angular JS
to monitor Asterisk event. 
I will be glad if you have any opinion on this matter.

Comment: `…but it doesn't work correctly` is not very helpful. Can you add some details explain what is happening.

Comment: What error you are getting??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Multiple problems can occure :

- It can be a CORS problem : (To avoid cors problem, I suggest you to use the npm package called "cors". It's pretty easy to use:

  const cors = require('cors')

  then simply add : `app.use(cors())` before your `app.listen(3000, function () {})`.
- It can be a parsing problem since you parse the `data` object manually
- It can be your url being wrong

Is `console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')` showing in your console ?

A good idea is to test your api/back-end using a tool like "postman" [postman website](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I didn't know this tools.

Comment: after correct my request from as same as postman I get this error from my request                                                                                                      Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.175:3000/endpoint' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: To avoid cors problem, I suggest you to use the npm package called "cors". It's pretty easy to use. 

const cors = require('cors') then app.use(cors()) before your app.listen(3000, function () {})

If this works for you, please accept my answer